# How to get all json values with newtonsoft

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm having a hard time getting through all the JSON values ​​of a string, can anyone help me?
I'm only getting a single value, where am I going wrong?

My codes

```
Dim address As String = "http://wsloterias.azurewebsites.net/api/sorteio/getresultado/1"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
Dim json = (reader.ReadToEnd)

Dim objs As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(json)
Dim objsSorteio As Sorteio = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Sorteio)(json)


For Each nums In objsSorteio.Premios
    MsgBox(nums.ToString)
Next
```

Classes

```
Public Class Premio
    Public Property Faixa() As String
        Get
            Return m_Faixa
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Faixa = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Faixa As String
    Public Property NumeroGanhadores() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_NumeroGanhadores
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_NumeroGanhadores = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_NumeroGanhadores As Integer
    Public Property Valor() As Double
        Get
            Return m_Valor
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            m_Valor = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Valor As Double
End Class

Public Class Sorteio
    Public Property NumSorteio() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_NumSorteio
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_NumSorteio = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_NumSorteio As Integer
    Public Property Numeros() As List(Of Integer)
        Get
            Return m_Numeros
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Integer))
            m_Numeros = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Numeros As List(Of Integer)
    Public Property Premios() As List(Of Premio)
        Get
            Return m_Premios
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Premio))
            m_Premios = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Premios As List(Of Premio)
    Public Property Ganhadores() As List(Of Object)
        Get
            Return m_Ganhadores
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Object))
            m_Ganhadores = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Ganhadores As List(Of Object)
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property NumeroConcurso() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_NumeroConcurso
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_NumeroConcurso = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_NumeroConcurso As Integer
    Public Property Acumulou() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_Acumulou
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_Acumulou = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Acumulou As Boolean
    Public Property EstimativaPremio() As Double
        Get
            Return m_EstimativaPremio
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            m_EstimativaPremio = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_EstimativaPremio As Double
    Public Property ValorAcumulado() As Double
        Get
            Return m_ValorAcumulado
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            m_ValorAcumulado = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ValorAcumulado As Double
    Public Property Data() As String
        Get
            Return m_Data
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Data = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Data As String
    Public Property RealizadoEm() As String
        Get
            Return m_RealizadoEm
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_RealizadoEm = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_RealizadoEm As String
    Public Property DescricaoAcumuladoOutro() As String
        Get
            Return m_DescricaoAcumuladoOutro
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_DescricaoAcumuladoOutro = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_DescricaoAcumuladoOutro As String
    Public Property ValorAcumuladoOutro() As Double
        Get
            Return m_ValorAcumuladoOutro
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            m_ValorAcumuladoOutro = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ValorAcumuladoOutro As Double
    Public Property DataProximo() As String
        Get
            Return m_DataProximo
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_DataProximo = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_DataProximo As String
    Public Property ValorAcumuladoEspecial() As Double
        Get
            Return m_ValorAcumuladoEspecial
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            m_ValorAcumuladoEspecial = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ValorAcumuladoEspecial As Double
    Public Property Arrecadacao() As Double
        Get
            Return m_Arrecadacao
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            m_Arrecadacao = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Arrecadacao As Double
    Public Property Sorteios() As List(Of Sorteio)
        Get
            Return m_Sorteios
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of Sorteio))
            m_Sorteios = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Sorteios As List(Of Sorteio)
End Class
```

I can not go through all the "Numeros" and also "Premios"

Comment: Auto implement properties will prevent you from having to write all that boilerplate code.  The json represents an entire `RootObject` object, so only the first deserializer code should work.  `objs.Sorteios.Premios` seems to be what you are after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over complicating this unnecessarily.

using the URL provided the exposed json data was copied and plugged into a utility site like http://jsonutils.com/. It generated the models with auto properties. Note that it converted collections to array as apposed to Lists like you have in your classes.

```
Public Class Premio
    Public Property Faixa As String
    Public Property NumeroGanhadores As Integer
    Public Property Valor As Double
End Class

Public Class Sorteio
    Public Property NumSorteio As Integer
    Public Property Numeros As Integer()
    Public Property Premios As Premio()
    Public Property Ganhadores As Object()
End Class

Public Class RootObject
    Public Property NumeroConcurso As Integer
    Public Property Acumulou As Boolean
    Public Property EstimativaPremio As Double
    Public Property ValorAcumulado As Double
    Public Property Data As String
    Public Property RealizadoEm As String
    Public Property DescricaoAcumuladoOutro As String
    Public Property ValorAcumuladoOutro As Double
    Public Property DataProximo As String
    Public Property ValorAcumuladoEspecial As Double
    Public Property Arrecadacao As Double
    Public Property Sorteios As Sorteio()
End Class
```

Basically the same as what you had originally with better readability. Feel free to convert tha arrays back to list if that is your preference.

The first desrialization is already giving you the necessary object. Drill into the properties in order to access the values you need.

```
'''other code removed for brevity
Dim objs As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(json)
Dim objsSorteioList As List(Of Sorteio) = objs.Sorteios.ToList()

For Each objsSorteio In objsSorteioList
    For Each prems In objsSorteio.Premios
        MsgBox(prems.ToString)
    Next
    For Each nums In objsSorteio.Numeros
        MsgBox(nums.ToString)
    Next
Next
```